# Fatal Error Zend_Uri Magento

Tags: magento, zend-framework, uri

Suddenly our Magento store has a fatal error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend_Uri' not found in /.../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php on line 726
```

No new plugins or modules have been added recently.
Compiler is not active, var/cache and var/session are empty.
Permissions are resetted for all magento folders / files.

No other errors or more information is provided, but i have a blank page - on frontend and backend.

Magento version 1.7.0.2. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 726 of the `Store.php` file looks like this

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php 
$uri = Zend_Uri::factory($secureBaseUrl);
```

That is, Magento's making a call to the static method `factory` on the `Zend_Uri` class.  Your error

> PHP Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Uri' not found

Indicates that PHP can't find the `Zend_Uri` class.  This could be because

- The class definition file is no longer there,
- Someone has changed the class definition file so it's no longer valid
- A local code pool override file exists and someone has edited the class override file so it's no longer valid
- Someone has edited the `lib/Varien/Autoload.php` so it can't load the `Zend_Uri` class file
- A local code pool override file exists for `Varien/Autoload.php` and someone has edited it so it can't load the `Zend_Uri` class file
- Someone has changed the php include path (normally defined in `app/Mage.php`) so it doesn't include the `lib` folder, or the code pool where a local code pool override might exist

I'd start by looking for the `Zend_Uri` class in `lib/Zend/Uri.php`, and then work your way down the list until you figure out why PHP isn't autoloading this class file.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alan, for your time and clear answers. 

A local code pool override file exists for Varien/Autoload.php and someone has edited it so it can't load the Zend_Uri class file


Someone has changed the php include path (normally defined in app/Mage.php) so it doesn't include the lib folder, or the code pool where a local code pool override might exist

These offered me the solution, so got it up running again.